Replacing $\mathbf{Cat}$ with a $2$-category in Grothendieck construction
Let $\mathbf{Cat}$ denote the (strict) $2$-category of categories, functors, and natural transformations. Let $F: C \to \mathbf{Cat}$ be a pseudofunctor from a $1$-category $C$ to $\mathbf{Cat}$. The associated Grothendieck construction is defined as the oplax colimit of $F$. This is an object $\int F$ of $\mathbf{Cat}$, i.e. a category. This category can be described concretely as follows. Its objects are pairs $(c, a)$ where $c$ (resp. $a$) is an object of $C$ (resp. $F(c)$). Morphisms are given by pairs $(f: c \to c', \phi: F(f)(a) \to a')$.
I would like to replace $\mathbf{Cat}$ with a more general $2$-category and retain a description of $\int F$ similar to the element-wise one above.
The Grothendieck construction is an oplax colimit, so we could try to replace $\mathbf{Cat}$, which I believe has all ((op)lax) (co)limits, by a general $2$-category $\mathscr D$ which has all oplax colimits, or at least oplax colimits of shape $F$. In this case, the oplax colimit is not itself a category, hence does not admit a characterisation as given above in the case of $\mathbf{Cat}$. What conditions do we need to put on $\mathscr D$ to get the desired description?
There is a notion of a concrete category, i.e. a category $\mathcal D$ which admits a faithful functor to the category of sets. I assume one can define a concrete $2$-category as a $2$-category equipped with a $2$-functor to $\mathbf{Cat}$ which satisfies some properties -- I am not sure "faithful" is quite the correct term here. A functor $F: C \to \mathscr D$ into a concrete $2$-category which has oplax colimits of shape $F$ should then admit the same element-wise description of $\int F$.
I have a hunch that requiring $2$-concreteness of $\mathscr D$ would be too strong a condition: homotopy categories are not concretisable by a result of Freyd, so I assume that an appropriately defined homotopy $2$-category $\mathscr H$ is not $2$-concretisable either. Nevertheless, one could imagine a Grothendieck construction on $F: C \to \mathscr H$, assuming it exists, to have a characterisation in terms of objects and (homotopy classes of) maps.
There is a notion of generalised element in category theory. Could a generalisation of it be of use here, giving a weaker form of the desired characterisation of $\int F$? I don't know very much $2$-category theory and I apologise for the vagueness of my question. Any hints would be welcome.

Note that Freyd’s non-concretizability result is a result of specific set theoretic axioms when we define the category of sets; there are set theories where the homotopy categories considered by Freyd are concretizable.

@Alec care to elaborate? The logic would have to be non-classical, of course.

@DavidRoberts Nothing fancy is necessary; anything that 'fails to be a set' in a given set theory can be made into a 'set' by moving to a stronger set theory, i.e. the set of all sets isn't a set but is a class. There will be things in these new theories that don't form objects of the theory (class of all classes etc.) but we can make these objects of a yet stronger theory. In any given fixed theory you will have some stuff like Freyd was talking about, but allowing your underlying theory to vary allows you to talk about anything you like as a 'set' in an appropriately large setting.
